# Django Rest Framework not validating all model's fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I searched for this problem everywhere without being able to find an answer though it seems basic DRF usage, so I might be missing sth.

I have a Customer model with certain required fields:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from applications.core.models.country import Country
from applications.core.models.customer_states.customer_state import \
    CustomerState


class Customer(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('customer')
        verbose_name_plural = _('customers')

    user_email = models.EmailField(_('email'), max_length=100, unique=True, default=None)
    complete_name = models.CharField(_('complete name'), max_length=200, default=None)
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone'), max_length=50, default=None)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('country'), default=None)
    city = models.CharField(_('city'), max_length=100, default=None)
    city_state = models.CharField(_('city state'), max_length=100, default=None)
    address = models.CharField(_('address'), max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(_('zip code'), max_length=50, default=None)
    customer_state = models.OneToOneField(CustomerState, models.PROTECT)
    notes = models.TextField(_('notes'), max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

And I have this serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from applications.core.models.customer import Customer
from applications.core.models.customer_states.implementations.pending_manual_validation_state import \
    PendingManualValidationState


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        self.add_default_state_if_missing(data)
        return super(CustomerSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)

    @staticmethod
    def add_default_state_if_missing(data):
        data['customer_state'] = PendingManualValidationState.objects.create().pk
```

Though I have explicitly told DRF that it should use all model's fields it does not seem to check for the requirement of fields like 'address' and whenever I create the serializer with data missing 'address' and call `serializer.is_valid()` it returns True.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by myself:

It would seem that `default=None` in the field makes DRF realize that even if the field is required, not receiving data for it is not a problem.

I set those default because otherwise Django would set a '' default value and thus, PostgreSQL would not raise exceptions for those empty data fields. But now that I am starting to use DRF for validations I no longer need those default.

Yet, if I happen to create and save a Customer without using the serializer, then I risk letting Django create a field with a default '' without having PostgreSQL complain about it. I figure that risk has a low probability though.